# Label Text Alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a Label the text set on label is dynamically at run time. My concern is Label is always center of screen. For this I take a label starting point is 0 and width is screenwidth and text alignment center.But I have issue Before starting I adjust a button just before text starting.How we make this button that start exactly before text start.
I am not do with code just do in xib.
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter

Comment: provide some code @varun malik

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using autolayout.

[image]

```
Drag an UILabel to xib and set constraints as follows.

1. Set align center X and align center Y to your label.
2. Set trailing space to superview >= 20.
3. Drag a UIButton left to your label and set horizontal spacing between them.
4. Set button's center Y aligned to label's center Y and set button's width to 50.
5. Finally set button's leading space to superview >= 20.
```

This will adjust your button and label for all iPhones.
Don't forget to set numberOfLines to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set button before label dynamically through the below steps:

1. You have to use `sizeToFit` property for that label.
2. Set that label center of the screen.
3. Get that label's x position using `label.frame.origin.x` and set that button before that label like `label.frame.origin.x-buttonWidth`.